# CSS position: absolute working on width but not height

Tags: css, css-position, absolute

I am trying to center a div in another div with absolute positioning. I am confused because the code works horizontally but not vertically.

```html
<div class="issue">
                <div class="issue__cover">
                        <span class="issue__look">look inside >></span>
                </div>
</div>
```

```
.issue {

    grid-column: issue-start / issue-end;
    grid-row: 2 / -1;
    position: relative;   
    height: 100%;
    width:100%;

    &__cover {
      position: absolute;

        width: calc(100% - 25rem);
        height: calc(100% - 10rem);
        top: 50%;
        margin-top: calc(((100% - 10rem)/2)*-1);
        left: 50%;
        margin-left: calc(((100% - 25rem)/2)*-1);
        background-image: url(../img/cover_2.jpeg);
        background-size: cover;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: top;
        z-index: 5;
    }

}
```

Comment: Hopefully I'm understanding the intended result. You could try wrapping the cover in a flex box and use align-center/justify-center to get it to sit perfectly in the middle. Flex box is good for getting a element perfectly centered on both axis. You would not need set positioning in that case.  https://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/demos/vertical-centering/

Comment: Is this css valid: `&__cover` ? I've never seen it used to concatenate class names.